# Google Maps API v3 within bootstrap inside of togglable tabs not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

I am attempting to use a google maps API while using Bootstrap 3.0's Togglable tabs.

I have made sure that the height of my map is forced in pixels so that it shows up, but the map is largely grey.

(I cannot show images because I do not have enough of a reputation score)

I then worked through some other posts by adding some JS which is supposed to re-size the map.  That solved the problem if the map wasn't within togglable tabs.

Unfortunately if I put the map in togglable tabs it goes right back to not rendering 75% of the map.   Is there a way to use the google maps API within togglable tabs for Bootstrap 3 and if so, is there 
something I am doing incorrectly?  Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>


    <title>Real Estate Crowd Investing</title>
    <meta name="viewport">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <!-- GOOGLE MAPS -->

          <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #map-canvas { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API KEY GOES HERE">

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = { 
          center: { lat: 28.563219, lng: -81.350211},
          zoom: 20
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
      google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){
          $(window).resize();
          map.setCenter(yourCoordinates);
      });
      $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($("#map_canvas").children().length > 0){    
            if (map)
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        }});
    </script>



    <!--/ Google maps-->
  </head>

   <section class="container">
  <!-- content -->        

<section class="row">
<br>
<br>
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">

  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#property" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Property</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#location" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Location  </a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">

  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="property"><?php include "_/components/php/5tab-listings-property.php"; ?></div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="location">

    <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 500px"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  </div>
</div>


</section>
</container>




    </section><!-- main -->
        </section><!-- container -->

    <script src="_/js/min/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 


</html>
```

Comment: Can you try setting a lower zoom level? 10 would be nice.

Comment: I can do any zoom level and the problem persists.